# flutter data passing issue between screens components without using global variables

Tags: android, flutter, error-handling, flutter-dependencies, solution

I am creating Screen components Separate to use such components like card, textfields so we can easily use it on web.
I am getting issue of passing data between components, Dont use the method of golbal varibales if i am sending data to components it only show componets but I want to send data to component but Navigate to main screen.

I am trying this method without creating Global variable file.

Answer (score 2):

you can use one of this ways:

1- Send your variables by constructor

```
class YourPgae extends StatefulWidget {
final int wabtedvar;
const YourPgae({super.key, required this.wabtedvar});

@override
State<YourPgae> createState() => _YourPgaeState();
}
```

2- Or, you can use state management library such as [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) to send variables globally without using global variable

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Card(value : 1);

class CardWidget extends StatelessWidget {

CardWidget(this.value);`enter code here`
int ? value  ;
}